# Calling web-service using WSE on Android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2, ksoap

I've been using the ksoap2 library for all of my SOAP calls and they have all been successful. But when I try to call a web-service that uses WSE I receive the following error...

Code: soap:Sender, Reason: WSE012: The input was not a valid SOAP message because the following information is missing: action.

From what I can tell, this means that the soap action is required in the header, but it clearly states in the documentation that SOAPAction is not a valid header for version 12. http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=67

When I do add it as header I simply receive a "server was unable to process request" error. I've been stuck on this for a while and was hoping someone knows what's up. Here is the main code...

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
request.addProperty(name, value);    
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
envelope.dotNet = true;  
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
try {
    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    List<HeaderProperty> headers = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    headers.add(new HeaderProperty("SOAPAction", soapAction));
    transport.call(soapAction, envelope, headers);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ksoap library excludes the soap action from the envelope on Soap VER12. This action is needed for WSE enhanced web services, so a simple change from VER12 to VER11 does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined soap action in your code like (namespace/soapAction) as per your wsdl,

```
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION_Auth = "http://AuthHeaderImplementation/Authentication";
```

One thing in your code,

```
transport.call(soapAction, envelope, headers);
```

According to [this](http://ksoap2.sourceforge.net/doc/api/org/ksoap2/transport/HttpTransport.html) ksoap2 doc, It takes only action and envelope as input parameter.

```
call(java.lang.String soapAction, SoapEnvelope envelope) 
      set the desired soapAction header field
```

And this is how i add empty header in my code, if required by server,

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    //Create empty Header
    Element [] header = new Element[1];
    header[0]=new Element();
               // add header to envelope
    envelope.headerOut = header;        
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

Comment: The call method has another constructor that allows headers to be added as a parameter. After looking even deeper into the code, the soapAction is never actually used in ver12. You can pass in a null parameter and it still works fine for non WSE web services. I'm not sure what the difference is between doing it that way or setting the envelope.headerOut. I'm just wondering what the purpose is of defining the soap action of that specific URL?